# How to send products as one description in PayPal?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hello I am using PayPal Express checkout. I was sending my cart to the request to API as

```
$item['product']['0']['name'];
$item['product']['0']['qty'];
$item['product']['0']['desc'];
$item['product']['0']['price'];
```

and I want to only send the description as *1 Quantity of item1, 2 Quantity of item2* is there any possibility in PayPal?

Comment: qty stands for quantity

Comment: Yes man I know about it. thanks

Comment: `$item['product']['0']['qty'] = 1; $item['product']['1']['qty'] = 2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement PayPal Express Checkout you need to do some server side code PHP. You have to do 3 API calls to validate a full payment.

**SetExpressCheckout**
**GetExpressCheckoutDetails**
**DoExpressCheckoutPayment or CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**

In each call you will use your API credentials.

To add several products loop this parameters ( use in methods SetExpressCheckout, DoExpressCheckoutPayment or CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile ):

> ```
>         L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION1
>         L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1
>         L_BILLINGTYPE1
>         L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1
>         L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1
>         L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1
> ```

**For each products must change the number at the end of the parameter**

Comment: Thanks sir, but i have send as `1 Quantity of itemone, 2 Quantity of nextitem...` as passage so I dont wanna use for each I have stored in only one description and one amount. Is any chance for my expectation either I'll follow you.

Comment: No way you must follow the paypal API rules